# Simple validation of editText not working (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, validation, android-edittext

I'm a beginner to Java and I want to validate an EditText. What I have in mind: my editText has to match "helloworld". When you press a button this has to be validated. If this is true--> go to a new class in which I have a setContentView to display a new layout.
If the text which I have just typed does **not** match "helloworld", it should do nothing. It seems very easy but since I'm a beginner you would help me BIGTIME!

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?

Comment: [Java String Comparison](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fdata%2Fcomparestrings.html&ei=pOiDUuvsD8qT2QWerICgCw&usg=AFQjCNF3Z_YhX4OrkuIOLJ0fEULdanZSLA&sig2=s4T_ht1ZoQ13sbxrFvYIMQ&bvm=bv.56343320,d.b2I) might be a start but we have no idea which part you are stuck on

Comment: You have listed so many steps that it is unclear which one you are stuck on. For example, you may already know how to invoke a method when a button is clicked, and you may know how to validate one string against another, but you may not know how to get the input string. Etc., etc. You will get better answers explain what steps you can deal with and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Please accept an answer once you have confirmed that the answer works for you. Also, comment on the answers that aren't working for you, but are close.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, and yes I should have been more specific. I used android:onClick="(my method)" on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's most of the logic handled. You will need to fill in your actual layout id's and make your launch intent. Put this code in your onCreate method in the activity with the layout that contains the edit text box

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBox);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkBtn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("helloworld")){
          //Launch activity with new view
       }

     }

});
```

Comment: thank you! this worked for me. What if I want to display a textview saying "error" when the editText doest not match "helloworld"?

Comment: You would need to add a text view to your layout. And then after the if ending bracket add an else statement with something like else{ ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.<yourtextviewid>)).setText("error");}

Comment: Thanks Joey, I accomplished it by making the textview in my xml file and using the setVisibility in the Java class.

Answer (score 0):

In an activity (or android class) you have to get the instance of your EditText. Your edit text has an id, and you can get it using R. R is the resources for your app.

```
EditText t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.<Name of your textfield>);
```

Then you can get the value of that textfield and compare it

```
t.getText().toString().equals("helloworld");
```

will return true or false. If you dont care about the case of the letters use

```
t.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("helloworld");
```

you will need an onClickListener for your button, check out the android api 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

in your onCreate, when declaring your submit button, add a listener

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(submitListener);
```

make a new onClick listener and fire an Intent to start a new activity

```
View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //if string matches helloworld fire new activity
        Intent newActivity = new Intent();
         startActivity(newActivity);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a reference to the EditText in your layout
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextIdInLayout);

// create a reference to the check Button in your layout
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonIdInLayout);    

// set up an onClick listener for the button reference
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String userInput = editText.getText().toString(); // get the user input
        if (userInput.equals("helloworld") // see if the input is "helloworld"
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.newLayout); // change the content view
        }
    }
});
```